# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de expresar "haunt" como cuando los muertos regresan para estorbar a los vivos?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Hay candidatos como acosar, acechar, rondar, perseguir, embrujar, pero no puedo encontrar el sentido expresamente para los fantasmas.

Answer (score 7):

Creo que la palabra que buscas es:

> Atormentar

La RAE define atormentar como:

[**Atormentar**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=atormentar)

De tormentar.

1. tr. Causar dolor o molestia corporal. U. t. c. prnl.
2. tr. Causar aflicción, disgusto o enfado. U. t. c. prnl.
3. tr. Dar tormento al reo o a un testigo para obtener una confesión.
4. tr. Batir con la artillería.

En el caso de los fantasmas lo que aplica es la definición 3º.

```
 El fantasma de la casa atormentaba a los habitantes.
```

> Por ejemplo, Nerón, quien había ordenado asesinar a su madre Agripina,
>   confesaba que vivía atormentado por su fantasma, que habitualmente lo
>   perseguía.[fuente](http://queaprendemoshoy.com/fantasmas-del-pasado-sucesos-paranormales-en-grecia-y-roma/)

Comment: La definición que propones no parece que tenga nada que ver con el asunto: ni es un reo o testigo, ni se busca una confesión. Otros usos de la palabra podrían encajar mejor pero aun así creo que *rondar* es la palabra más habitual hablando de fantasmas.

Comment: @blonfu "atormentar" me parece una buena elección. En realidad, las definiciones 3 y 4 de la RAE me parecen muy poco felices. Nadie diría: *La policía atormenta al reo para hacerlo confesar* sino *tortura*. *rondar* está bien pero suele usarse como verbo intransitivo y tal vez suene algo coloquial, como que el fantasma no es demasiado temible. :)

Comment: @Gustavson puedo aceptar *atormentar* pero con otra definición, por ejemplo esta de word reference: **atormentar** *vtr figurado* (molestar profundamente)

Comment: @blonfu En realidad la acepción 2 de la RAE también se adecuaría. "He was haunted by his past: Lo atormentaba el pasado."

Comment: @Gustavson Sí, también serviría pero me parecía un poco suave *aflicción*, *disgusto* y *enfado*

Comment: Otros sinónimos: aterrorizado (si la víctima es una persona), habitado/asolado (si el objeto encantado es una casa o un lugar)

Comment: Atormentar me parece que es la que más se adecúa aunque la definición de la RAE no está orientada hacia los fantasmas

Comment: [Aquí](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?tormento) pueden leer la etimología de _atormentar_ y su relación con la _tormenta_, a mí me sorprendió.

Answer (score 2):

En varios países latinoamericanos decimos que un fantasma viene a **penar**.

> **[penar](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=penar)**.
>
> **I. 1.**   intr. Ni, Co, Ve, Pe, Bo, Ch. Aparecerse o manifestarse un fantasma o un alma en pena.

Por ejemplo, te puedo amenazar diciendo que *si no cumples tu promesa, una vez muerto te voy a venir a penar*. O aconsejarte que no vayas a determinado lugar porque *ahí en la noche penan*.